# White space on right side of header on zoom

Tags: html, css

I am developing [this](http://www.brilliantseotechnologies.com/test.html) website.

The problem I am facing is white space on right side of header on zoom in. I did all sorts of things but failed to fill the white with area of header part with black.

Relevant CSS code: (I am not pasting the whole code as it is too lengthy, you can find it in the website)

```
header
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    background:#000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
}

.header_main
{
    background: #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 5px;
    float:left;
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of issues , follow as suggested below:

1 `.slideshow{margin: -10px 0 0 50px;}` Remove this line from the class .slideshow

2  `.headrouter{ padding-left:100px; width:1200px;}` Remove padding-left and set width:1100px

3  `#site_content {margin-left:50px; }` remove margin-left

4  Add overflow-x:hidden to body like below:

```
       body {
       background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
       font: 80% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
       overflow-x: hidden;
      }
```

That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because on your http://www.brilliantseotechnologies.com/css/2nav.css you have width:98% for your `ul.menu` class