# Website is displaying a white space on right side of screen in iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, ios, css, removing-whitespace

I am having a problem on http://eiglaw.com -- an approximately 25px wide white space/border is showing on the right side of the screen on iPhone. I researched the problem on stackoverflow and these posts are relevant but when I tried the various solutions offered I have not been able to fix the problem:

[Responsive website on iPhone - unwanted white space on rotate from landscape to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004707/responsive-website-on-iphone-unwanted-white-space-on-rotate-from-landscape-to)

[Website body background rendering a right white margin in iPhone Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804441/website-body-background-rendering-a-right-white-margin-in-iphone-safari)

[White space on right side of header on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184160/white-space-on-right-side-of-header-on-zoom)

I had a similar problem on iPad but was able to fix it with this media query:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
/*and (orientation : landscape)*/ {
html,
body {
width:1000px; 
}
}
```

I have tried various media queries targeting the html and body elements with no luck. I have looked through the entire CSS file for problems with background images, margins, padding, overflows, etc., but am really stumped. Does anyone out there have any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trouble is in your `<h3 class="menu-toggle">Menu</h3>` (why h3, btw?), which appears to be wider than a viewport because of having `width: 100%` + some padding.

Try setting a `box-sizing: border-box;` to that element.

Comment: This completely worked! So the lesson to take from this is that any element having a width of 100% should not have any left or right padding. If it does, iOS will add that and display a blank area to the right equal to that extra padding.

Comment: That's not about the iOS, problem is reproducible on other browsers as well.

Whenever you use `width: 100%` with padding, you must set `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid overlapping.

Comment: I've just solved the same problem here with this... The problem was that one of my titles was larger than 100%... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked a treat Tigran.

I just added a global class at the top of my stylesheet:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following styles:

```css
body{
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

this will remove the overflow on the both side of the screen i.e extra white space on the screen

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

iOS is trash and the only way to find a solution to why half your screen goes white and you keep scrolling into it is becoming a friggin programmer apparently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Try this

iPhone 5 - Landscape

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape) { }
```

iPhone 5 - Portrait

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait) { }
```

iPhone 4

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) { }
```

Comment: Don't know, because that I said "Try this".