# White bar on the right if visiting from mobile

Tags: html, css, styles

I am trying to figure out why my website shows a white bar on the right when i visit it on my smartphone.
www.pestenvettem.hu

I have added this to my style-sheet, but no success:

```
html, body {        
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also used firebug, but still no idea.

Please advise

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947793/website-is-displaying-a-white-space-on-right-side-of-screen-in-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its your submit button in the header. Because of its absolute positioning, it manages to crawl outside your container. The fastest way to get rid of it would be setting `right:0;` to it.